# Drop down menu animation gets stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

The animation of the drop down menu gets stuck while it is supposed to create a slide effect animation

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/73/

This is the css that may have caused the problem but it is necessary to my code
(it makes the bottom div's of my site stationary) so it cannot be changed.

```
    #nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

  #nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You HTML is badly formed. You can't have `divs` as children of a `ul`.

Comment: @Paulie_D what do you mean? can you be more specific?

Comment: You can't have divs as direct children of a ul, only `li` are allowed.

Comment: @Paulie_D can you suggest a fix?it is related with my problem?

Comment: Take all the link-wrapper divs out and start over.

Answer (score 1):

With this your code is already more valid

```
       <div id="top_menu">
  <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="links_wrapper"><a href="about_us.html" title=" About us">ABOUT US</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Customers</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="links_wrapper"><a href="solution.html">SOLUTIONS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"> Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">General Descreption</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Detailed Descreption</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="links_wrapper"><a href="customers.html">CUSTOMERS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"> Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">General Descreption</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Detailed Descreption</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="links_wrapper"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">General Descreption</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Descreption</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>        
    <div id="login">LOGIN</div>
    <div id="lang_btn"><a href="#">He</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#">En</a>
    </div><!--close nav-->
</div><!--top menu-->
```

You should from time to time test your code inside W3C's validator

http://validator.w3.org/